# GAN pytorch loss functions doesn't seem to work

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

What could I be doing wrong. I am trying to implement discriminator loss. When I use the function when training I get wrong values. I don't understand much about GAN, I have been using some tutorials.

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch.nn.functional import binary_cross_entropy_with_logits as bce_loss

def discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake):
    """
    Computes the discriminator loss.
    
    You should use the stable torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits 
    
    Inputs:
    - logits_real: PyTorch Tensor of shape (N,) giving scores for the real data.
    - logits_fake: PyTorch Tensor of shape (N,) giving scores for the fake data.
    
    Returns:
    - loss: PyTorch Tensor containing (scalar) the loss for the discriminator.
    """
    
    loss = None
    
    ones = np.ones(logits_real.shape) + np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1)
    
    zeros = np.zeros(logits_real.shape) + np.random.uniform(0, 0.2)
    ones = torch.from_numpy(ones).float()
    zeros = torch.from_numpy(zeros).float()

    loss_real = bce_loss(logits_real, ones)
    loss_fake = bce_loss(logits_fake, zeros)
    loss = loss_fake + loss_real
    
    return loss
def generator_loss(logits_fake):
    """
    Computes the generator loss.

    Inputs:
    - logits_fake: PyTorch Tensor of shape (N,) giving scores for the fake data.
    
    Returns:
    - loss: PyTorch Tensor containing the (scalar) loss for the generator.
    """
    
    loss = None
    
    ones = torch.ones_like(logits_fake)
    loss = bce_loss(logits_fake, ones)
    
    return loss
```

Comment: try with `loss = loss_real - loss_fake` to see if it's converge.